# Is it possible to feed a chili bean to a rampaging bull?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

The rampaging bull is rather annoying as it charges forward quite a ways before flinging the midget zombie into my back row.  Is it possible to feed a chili bean to it so it will pass gas and eliminate any other zombie in that row behind it?  I don't have a tall nut yet as I'm playing the Big Bad Butte level and I haven't gotten it through cards yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the bull eats the chili bean without effect.

Thought if it helps, the bull charges until he encounters a plant, then bucks and throws the midget zombie. So having something far up in the lane where he appears will at least prevent him from charging too far, and consequently prevent the midget from being thrown too far in. Wall-nuts up in front are still a good idea. (and it'll at least slow down the bull, which is certainly a big enough problem in itself...)

Given the midget isn't too terribly hard to kill, in most cases you should have adequate defense built by the time they show up to get him. I might lose a sunflower to him before I bring him down, but that's not too terrible a loss.